# Auto width of child to absolutely positioned parent

Tags: html, css

I would like to make the width of the tooltip (`.tooltip-text`) automatically adjust it's text content length. At the moment it takes the width of it`s parent and wraps the text accordingly. It's this possible without using any js?

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;   
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 125%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<h2>Tooltip</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

<div class="tooltip">
  <div> Hover me </div> 
    <div class="tooltiptext">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. 
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by saying auto width? Do you want its content to spread over on one single line with no wrapping and adapt the size of the container to fit it? `width: max-content;` will suffice. Do you mean to give it a fixed size upfront like 20rem and wrap text? `width: 20rem;`. With absolute positioned elements you are forced to deal with widths that don't depend on the document flow, parents and so on

Comment: There is a spelling error. In your question you are referring to `.tooltip-text` (with **hyphen**) whereas in, the code snippet, you are using `.tooltiptext`. Please use one, as it may cause confusion.

Comment: If you know for sure where the component would be appearing, then you can apply the width: max-content solution and then tweak the arrow position to match.

Else the only sure shot would be to use JS or a library so that the tooltip will be rendered depending on the position of the element and saving you a lot of headache.

Answer (score 3):

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext {
    width: max-content;
    max-width: 440px;
}
```

Comment: Did you check your solution?

It is not a proper solution as the text will be clipped off if the tooltip is anywhere around the sides.